# List of WebElements showing count as 1 using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, size, webdriverwait

> I have list of web element, when I apply listName.size() function on
>   list, it shows count as 1.
>   Where as in actual the count is not 1.

Below things I have tried -

> 1. Tried applying implicit and explicit wait in order to load the long list of web elements properly.
> 2. Tried wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(listName));

java code :

```
List<WebElement> listName= driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
int count = listName.size();
```

I want the count exact as the number elements of list found by using xpath.
Note: The xpath is valid and correct. Can locate the elements manually with that xpath.

Comment: how many elements you get from manually. Please post your html.

Comment: @Dhru'soni - manually I get all expected elements. I cant post html due to privacy.

Comment: You can put few elements html code on your original post

Comment: Xpath is correct ? How many entries are present when you search that xpath in DOM ?

Comment: Yes, xpath is correct. The list contains the 32 element

Comment: That's fine, if xpath is correct then there shouldn't be any issue. How did you check the DOM anyway ? Please use @ to mention someone in comment.

Comment: I think the wait is only soultion

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to print the `size()` of the *List* matching a specific [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) instead of using `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use either of the following solutions:

- [`visibilityOfAllElements(WebElement... elements)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElements-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement...-):

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath")))).size());
  ```
- [`visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-):

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("xpath"))).size());
  ```